# Choosing a random bit from a bitmap

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, sampling

Since, I don't have strong algorithmic background my question may sound a litlle odd. Please correct me, if so.

I have quite a large bitmap (~100 Million bits) (e.g. `100100101001010001001...010010`). The bitmap is just an example, it doesn't have to start with `1` or end with `0`.

Now, I need to choose *randomly* any `0`-bit from the bitmap and retrieve it's position. Memory is not an issue in my case, I can maintain a few copies of the bitmap, if necessary. But the acceptable complexity of the  algorithm would be linear or `O(n lnn)` in the worst case. Couldn't you advice a direction to move to? I'll appreciate any advices or refernces to some related resources.

Comment: Practically speaking, bitmaps usually contain a decent fraction of zeroes, and so the trivial randomized algorithm works in $O(1)$ random accesses. Should your algorithm work in the worst case? Is random access for free? Do you care about time, space or both? Please state your exercise in full.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus _Should your algorithm work in the worst case?_ Yes. _Is random access for free?_ Yes. almost for free, it's very inexpensive in my case. _Do you care about time, space or both?_ About time.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus _bitmaps usually contain a decent fraction of zeroes, and so the trivial randomized algorithm works in O(1) random accesses._ What do you mean trivial randomizer? Couldn't you expland a bit or give a refernce?

Comment: Buzzword: rejection sampling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a simple $O(n)$ algorithm using the technique of *reservoir sampling*. Keep a currently selected element $x$ (initially, none). Go over all bits in the file in order. When seeing the $m$th zero, put it in $x$ with probability $1/m$. You can show (exercise) that the final contents of $x$ is a uniformly random zero from the file.

If you are allowed preprocessing, you can store the locations of all zeroes in a new file, and then choose a uniformly random zero in $O(1)$ by choosing a uniformly random position in the list.

Practically speaking, we expect bitmaps to contain a decent fraction of zeroes – say at least 1%. This suggests querying uniformly random locations in the file until you reach a zero. The expected runtime of this algorithm is at most 100 random queries.

Comment: The question may sound dumbly, but there's no constant time algorith for such bitmaps even if the random has a constant-time complexity, isn't?

Comment: @St.Antario It depends on the model and the assumptions.